# How can you modify a cordova plugin that utilizes the native camera so that the safe areas on iPhone X are respected?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, xib

I have an Ionic 4 app and I have successfully installed a QR Scanner cordova plugin. Located here: https://github.com/AndreiTelteu/cordova-plugin-qr-barcode-scanner

My problem arises with the safe areas on the iPhone X. The plugin has a toolbar that goes into the bottom safe area.

Example Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6sqP.jpg

My question is where do you even begin to modify the plugin to set the safe areas?

I have opened the scannerOverlay.xib in Xcode Interface Builder and clicked a setting called "Use Safe Area Layout Guides".

I installed this modified .xib file back into the project, re-added the plugin, and again the toolbar is in the bottom safe area.